# UTF-8 Charset doesn't affects on the page

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Today I've a strange problem I never saw before, I declared page charset to utf-8 with:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

But the page shows my Persian texts messed up and weird...
I also put this code in my PHP code but It didn't solve my problem:

```
echo '<meta charset="utf-8">';
```

After some check, I think the problem is with this piece of code because when I comment it, the page loads with utf-8 charset and texts are showed correctly:

```
$novingostar = mysql_pconnect($hostname_novingostar, $username_novingostar, $password_novingostar) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

I'll so happy if you help my with my problem.